# Can't change time before password is required after sleep or screen saver starts

Tags: macbook-pro, password, mojave, screensaver

I recently upgraded to Mojave on my 2015 MBP.  I had the time before password is required after sleep or screen saver begins set at 1 hour which is what it still says in System Preferences but I noticed that, after the upgrade, it requires a password as soon as the screen saver starts.  Although the setting is not greyed out, it does not retain any change i.e. I pull the drop down and click '15 minutes' and the drop down still says '1 hour' (which is also not what's actually happening either).

Comment: is the locking/unlocking (bottom left) working ?

Comment: @Buscar웃 - yes.  the UI is acting as expected yet it doesn't actually change.